# How do I switch between images using a timer? (set Interval)

Tags: javascript

I have this code, and i would like to switch images using a set interval timer. Please help me, thanks!

[The code, help me please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH1OZ.png)

Comment: Please add the code to this post. No need for a picture of it. If the service hosting the picture is shutting down, the question will get useless.

Comment: two issues, 1) missing comma after the array assignment, 2) don't call the `changeImage` function, just pass it without invoking `()`.

Answer (score 2):

in `setInterval()` you need to pass function reference not call the function yourself.

use :

```
setInterval(changeImage,1000);
```

instead of

```
setInterval(changeImage(),1000);
```